# DayJS historical date format issue

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

DayJS format() incorrectly converts almost any historical date. In this example I try to format the year 2 AD (from user input). The output is the year 1902 AD, which is absolutely wrong. Now I am wondering if I got this method wrong or it is actually a bug and of course how to solve this anyway.

Have created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/adrian-is-testing/pen/mdpvEKx) for this

```
const formatedDate = dayjs('0002-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(formatedDate)
//Output: "1902-05-01"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1237) somebody [solved](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1237#issuecomment-732797209) this with setting **new Date().setFullYear(2)**. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this issue and the solution. Meanwhile there is a fix PR but not yet merged.

Answer (score 0):

In case it could be useful to someone you can simply use Date to overcome this issue.

```
const dateStr = '0002-05-01';
dayjs(new Date(dateStr)).format()
```